# Snapshot based S3 bucket backup solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to build a backup system for some important data in my AWS S3 bucket.
Among the options that I explored were versioning from which individual objects can be recovered to an earlier state.
This would definitely help in the case of accidental deletions.

But the problem here is in situations where there's a data corruption happening because of some wrong code that was introduced or something similar, in order to retrieve the system to an earlier state a proper snapshot based backup solution will be required in addition to versioning.
This would also help in a situation where say the whole bucket was deleted accidentally, or versioning got turned off and some data got deleted later.

The current option I was thinking of was to use an EC2 instance to copy the data daily or at predefined intervals to local drive(using aws s3 sync or aws s3 cp) and then upload it under the particular days folder to another S3 bucket. I was thinking of maintaining a life-cycle rule to expire the backups after say a week.
I don't think this is very efficient though because the buckets could hold about 100GB data later as traffic increases into the application.

I wanted some validation from someone who might have done something similar if this is the right way to proceed, or if there's some S3 or AWS feature that can be used to make this simpler.

Comment: You can use S3 replication to replicate objects into another bucket either inside the same region or cross region.

Comment: With replication I think data corruption will also get replicated real-time.

Comment: I think your problem is more detect corruption rather than recover from there. The earlier you can detect corruption the faster and easy and simple the recover solution will be. Simply try to implement a fast way to detect when the data is corrupted, and using S3 versioning you can go back to the earliest stable version. Are you expecting to have the same files over time in a bucket? Because if that is not the case, then versioning may not be the best. You keep versions for things that change over time, but not for things that get created and remove on time basis.

Comment: I don't think detecting corruption is that straightforward to identify all possible use-cases and implement. It could be just an untested scenario in code which might mess up the data. But even if it, having a defensive strategy is good to have albeit expensive for critical data in case the need arises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditionally, backups are used in case a storage device is corrupted. However, Amazon S3 replicates data automatically to multiple storage devices, so this takes care of **durability**.

For **data corruption** (eg an application destroys the contents of a file), [Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) is the best option because S3 will retain previous versions of an object whether an object is updated (overwritten). [Object Lifecycle Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) can be used to delete versions after a certain number of versions or after a given period of time.

If you concerned that **versioning might be turned off** (suspended) or a **whole bucket was accidentally deleted**, you can use [S3 replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) to duplicate the contents of the bucket to another bucket. The other bucket can even be in a different region or a **different AWS Account**, which means that nobody in the primary account would have permission to delete data in the secondary (replication) account. This is a **common practice** to ensure critical business data is not lost.

If you want the ability to **restore multiple objects to a point-in-time** ("retrieve the system to an earlier state"), you can use traditional backup software that is S3-aware. For example, [MSP Backup (formerly CloudBerry Lab)](https://www.msp360.com/) has backup software that can move data between S3 buckets and on-premises storage (or just within S3), with normal point-in-time restore capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I am not at liberty to use external applications, do you think the way I suggested(using an EC2) would also work.

Comment: Personally, it does not sound like a clever idea. You would be building a solution that is less capable than what S3 can offer itself. If your primary requirement is "restore all objects at a particular point-in-time", you could write a few lines of Python to iterate through the S3 objects, look at the date of each versioned file, and then restore those particular versions. Much easier than making yet more copies of the data, in a less-durable storage medium (Amazon EBS, compared to Amazon S3), requiring more operational overhead.

Comment: Also if the bucket contains millions of data, will you still suggest this ? If I were to restore only the latest version of each object will I be better off using some pipeline like AWS Glue to periodically store backups.

Comment: AWS Glue is ideal for processing and transforming flows of data. I do not see it as being applicable for managing data backups. If anything, the more objects that are in a bucket, the more reason to use Versioning since a very small proportion of the files would change over a given time period, compared to having to backup so many files on a regular basis.

Comment: I tried creating a script to restore a buckets data based on versions last modified field to a point in time. The problem is if there are many objects to be deleted to restore to a point in time, its really slow. I couldn't find any API also to batch operations to reduce network calls. If we have to delete the most recent 1M items to get the bucket back to a secure state, I feel this could be a bottleneck for the script. Any recommendations ?

Comment: This depends on what you are actually wanting to achieve. I doubt you will want to delete so many objects just to get back to a state that represents a point-in-time. It would mean that you are deleting data that you probably can't get back again. One option might be the ability to "roll-back" specific objects to a desired version at that point-in-time, or you might want to populate another bucket with all objects as at that point-in-time. If this is functionality you definitely want, I would suggest paying a few dollars for a backup system app understands how to do this.